# Evaluation of Spence's function.

Tags: integration, logarithms, special-functions

[Spence's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function) is defined as $${\rm Li}_2 (z)=-  \int_0^z \frac{\ln(1-u)}{u} \, du $$ where $$z  \in {\mathbb C}  \setminus [1, \infty )$$ For $|z|<1 $ $${\rm Li}_2 (z)=  \sum_1^ \infty   \frac{ z^k }{ k^2 } $$ Here the sum is over $k$. All this information is from Wiki. Can someone help me to find out how to evaluate the integral?

Comment: for specific values?

Comment: Nope. Indefinite integral.

Comment: I don't think there's a closed form otherwise why would we define dilogarithm like this? btw it is also called dilgorithm.

Comment: @ADG We could quibble over semantics, but I don't think there's anything wrong with saying $Li_2(z)$ is a closed form for the indefinite integral.

Comment: I came to know from this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEAQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmaths.dur.ac.uk%2F~dma0hg%2Fdilog.pdf&ei=tgYsVc_aBIafugThmoGABg&usg=AFQjCNH5M_4yZ5AhgemndFhs642pTGmtYQ&sig2=aNl_34IH9vDTq7H18jgGng) the dilogarithm has only eight known specific values.

Comment: This integral has a series representation. I want to know how it is evaluated.

Comment: do you want to convert integral into series?

Comment: Wiki says the dilogarithm is the result of the integration. But how it is done?

Comment: @KaziArafatAhmed The result of the integral is the dilogarithm by definition because the dilogarithm is defined as being the result of the integral. It's that simple.

Comment: @KaziArafatAhmed its like asking for the indefinite integral of $1/x$, we don't actually have explicit values for the whole function, but we do have a name for it, the natural log $\ln(x)$. Its the same situation here. You can Taylor expand the series however, and get approximations...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Expand $\ln(1-u)$ into its [Mercator series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series), and then reverse the order of summation and integration.